# Impersonating a user as LocalSystem on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, impersonation, privileges

I have a process that runs as LocalSystem on Windows XP and following. I am trying to find a way to have it start another process impersonating another user **without** having to provide the user password.

In principle this should be possible as LocalSystem has the privilege "Act as part of the operating system". But I am unable to find the correct API.

Can somebody tell me how to do this either:

- with an API, or
- from a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by first getting the token of the user via [`WTSQueryUserToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then calling [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start the process. Note that you can only do this for a user who is currently logged-in in the system.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just to verify, I would use WTSOpenServer with "\\.\" to get a handle for the current machine, WTSEnumerateSessions to get the available session ids, WTSQueryUserToken to get a user token for one of the sessions and CreateProcessAsUser to launch the process?

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke you can simply call `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` to get the active session id. Also, don't forget to duplicate the token by calling `DuplicateTokenEx`.

Comment: +1.  To expand on this a little: it is theoretically possible (but probably rather difficult) to do the same thing for a user who is not logged in, although the resulting process wouldn't have access to any encrypted data or over the network.  I believe you would do this by registering as a SSP/AP and using CreateTokenEx and related functions, but I've never tried so I don't know what sort of problems you might run into.